# Is there is good way to send an email to a user after 5 minutes of inactivity on an Account?

Tags: email, governorlimits, bestpractice, asynchronous, wait-element

An indeterminate number of images will be attached to Lead records.
We have a requirement that 5 minutes after the last image is attached, the Lead owner should automatically receive an email.

I've thought of one approach to this:
Every time an image is attached to a Lead record, schedule a job to happen 5 minutes later.
When the job executes 5 minutes later, check for images uploaded in the last five minutes and/or for more similar pending jobs.
If anything is found, do nothing.
If nothing is found, send the email.

But I expect this could burn through our async limits pretty quickly (assuming there are a lot of leads and many images are uploaded.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the scheduled job checking, have the scheduler check when scheduling the job. If a job already exists, abort it. Then, schedule a new one. This gives you an exact five minutes of delay instead of a variable delay between 5 and 10 minutes, and reduces the asynchronous usage accordingly.